# RSPEC passes with method, but am i missing the point?

Tags: ruby, rspec, stub

So I'm running my method against this rspec and everything passes. But I can't help but think that the time.stub's should be throwing it off, is there something I'm missing as to why they are not?
Even if the method passes, how is the information in the rspec that's above the method applicable to the situation?

This is my method:

```
def measure(num=1, &block)

n=0
arr = []
while n <= num-1
    a=Time.now
    block.call
    b=Time.now
    arr << (b-a)
    n += 1
end
sum = arr.inject(:+)
    avgtime = sum/num
end
```

This is part of my rspec file:

```
@eleven_am = Time.parse("2011-1-2 11:00:00")
it "takes exactly 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second (with stubs)" do
  fake_time = @eleven_am
  Time.stub(:now) { fake_time }
  elapsed_time = measure do
    fake_time += 60  # adds one minute to fake_time
  end
  elapsed_time.should == 60
end

it "returns the average time, not the total time, when running multiple times" do
  run_times = [8,6,5,7]
  fake_time = @eleven_am
  Time.stub(:now) { fake_time }
  average_time = measure(4) do
    fake_time += run_times.pop
  end
  average_time.should == 6.5
end
```

Comment: What's exactly your point you think you're missing?

Comment: shouldn't the time.stub mess up the ability to use time.now in my method? if not, what is the purpose os all the information in the rspec file that is before the method call

Comment: Time.stub(:now) just replaces the core implementation of that method with your stubbed version, which in this case returns your modified time values.  It's why your tests work.

Comment: in that case, wouldn't the time.now just be the same value for both a and b making all the time elapses 0?

Comment: No, since you explicitly change `fake_time` between the calls to `Time.now`, which returns this `fake_time`. 

See your lines:

`fake_time += 60  # adds one minute to fake_time` 

and 

`fake_time += run_times.pop`.